# c how to start a thread that is stopped by changing value of semaphore

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

I'm trying to learn about threading and semaphores. I want to be able to start and stop a thread. I have some code below that creates a thread and then stops because the value of `semaphore` is 0 so `sem_wait()` will not return. How do I change the value of `semaphore` in `main()` so that I can start the thread? For example, if I enter a char with `getchar()` then start the thread? I tried using `sem_post()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

sem_t semaphore;

void threadfunc() {
    printf("thread started\r\n");
    while (1) {
        sem_wait(&semaphore);
        printf("Hello from da thread!\n");
        sem_post(&semaphore);
        sleep(1);
    }
}

int main(void) {

    // initialize semaphore, only to be used with threads in this process, set value to 1
    sem_init(&semaphore, 0, 0);

    pthread_t *mythread;

    mythread = (pthread_t *)malloc(sizeof(*mythread));

    // start the thread
    printf("Starting thread, semaphore is locked.\n");
    pthread_create(mythread, NULL, (void*)threadfunc, NULL);


    sem_wait(&semaphore);

    getchar();
    //Now start the thread

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but why do you allocate memory for `mythread` dynamically? Why not use a plain non-pointer variable and use the address-of operator `&` to get a pointer to it when needed (like you do with `semaphore`)?

Comment: Why is `main` waiting on the semaphore as well? Why is `threadfunc()` posting to it?

Comment: Please show what you tried with `sem_post`

Comment: There should be a `sem_post` in `main()` or in some function called from `main()`

Comment: `(void*)threadfunc` looks odd. `pthread_create` requires a function pointer with the type `void * (*) (void*)`.

Answer (score 2):

The issue I see here is that `main()` is never getting to the `getChar()` call, since you called `sem_wait()` within it.

Try this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

sem_t semaphore;

void* threadfunc(void*) {
    printf("thread started\r\n");
    while (1) {
        // Wait for main to post to the semaphore
        sem_wait(&semaphore); 

        printf("Hello from da thread!\n");

        // Post to the semaphore ourselves since main will only do one
        sem_post(&semaphore);
        sleep(1);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t mythread;
    sem_init(&semaphore, 0, 0);

    // start the thread
    printf("Starting thread, semaphore is locked.\n");
    pthread_create(&mythread, NULL, threadfunc, NULL);

    getchar();
    sem_post(&semaphore);

    // Wait for threadfunc to return, otherwise our program dies early.
    pthread_join(&mythread, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

In this, `threadfunc()` waits on a semaphore who's initial value is `0`. `main()` immediately proceeds to the `getchar()` call, after which the semaphore is posted to, allowing `threadfunc()` to proceed.

Another key here is the call to `pthread_join()` at the end of `main()`. This causes `main()` to wait for `threadfunc()` to return before it continues. Once `main()` returns, your program will be torn down by the OS, whether your thread has finished or not.

In this case, `threadfunc()` will run forever, and `main()` will never return.

Also note the changed return type for `threadfunc()`. pthreads expects a function which takes and returns a `void*` parameter. Your cast was just hiding that your function did not have the correct signature. (Thanks @mch)